# SQL Server: DateTime and GMT or UMT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know which format SQL Server saves datetimes, GMT or UMT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `DATETIME` value in SQL Server has no knowledge of time zones and thus doesn't really care about time zones - that's entirely up to you to manage.

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME
SET @MyDate = '20100922 04:05:06'   --- no information on timezone
```

See [MSDN docs on DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

With SQL Server 2008, a new data type was introduced called [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) which stores time along with a timezone offset. So here, you can store the local time and store the timezone that time is local to as well.

```
DECLARE @MyDateOffset DATETIMEOFFSET
SET @MyDateOffset = '20100922 04:05:06 +09:00'  -- UTC plus 9 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither, it just returns the values in a specific format but stores it in a format without a timezone.